# Sitecore User Group Bangalore - December 15, 2019

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

**Date/Time(IST)**: December 15, 2019, 9:30 a.m.

**Date/Time(UTC)**: December 15, 2019, 4:00 a.m.

**Location**: 
Indegene Pvt Ltd.
3rd Floor, Aspen G-4 Block,
Manyata Embassy Business Park
Nagawara, Outer Ring Rd,
Bengaluru, Karnataka 560045

**RSVP**: http://sugblr.in/meetup-indegene-december-2019/

**Twitter**: @sugblr

[image]

Comment: Please add the UCT time for this meeting.

Comment: Done. Thanks for letting me know.